# Multiple developers sharing one Ubuntu LTS Server

Tags: server

I've been trying to figure out for many weeks, if there's a best practice for properly configuring a Ubuntu LTS Server. Each developer wants to have their little environment to run our code in and do tests, and then eventually merge into production.

I've been reading a lot, with no clear answer. I am sure there's no right or wrong. However, there can be recommendations and best practices.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I will use docker containers for this. Create a machine with the minimum software + docker, and give docker access to users. They will be able to run their own software as containers without messing up the host machine.

Comment: Docker is one of the virtualization choices in the Wikipedia list below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualize the server. That lets each of you have the OS and environment each of them wants, while sharing the same server as you specified. Suggest you go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software, copy and paste that chart into the spreadsheet of your choice, and filter out everything which does not support Linux as **Guest OS** (43 choices), filter out everything which does not have **x86-64** as **Host CPU** (48 choices available), then from the surviving virtual systems, go to the second table and filer out those with *Speed relative to Host OS* not near-native or better.

Comment: We want to share one. Because we have production and development.

Comment: Yes, you can! as The Man said.

Comment: What about MongoDB? Do I need to make replica sets?

Comment: That is another question to pose here; maybe phrase it like "If I have a virtual server running Docker/GNOME Boxes/KVM/VirtualBox/VMware/Xen, how may I set up MongoDB for multiple developers and also production use so I don't need replica sets?" Over  my head, I'm afraid, but I can point you in the right direction, at least. House rule here: One question or issue per post, so StackExchange accumulates useful answers to lotsa questions.